# If two vectors are almost the same, then probability is close to 1

Tags: probability, trigonometry, inequality, probability-distributions, vectors

Consider a random, $d$-dimensional vector $\vec x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ following a standard multivariate normal distribution, i.e. $\vec x \sim \mathcal{N}(\vec 0, \mathbb{I}_d)$ consisting of $d$ iid standard normal variables as coordinates.

If we consider two vectors $\vec a, \vec b\in\mathbb{R}^d$ that are "very close" to each other (they are almost the same vector), in the sense that their Euclidean distance is (strongly) very small, i.e. for some $\epsilon>0$ that can become arbitrarily close to $0$: $$ \| \vec a - \vec b \|_2 \leq \epsilon \| \vec a \|_2 $$

Then my intuition would suggest that the following probability (over the choice of the multivariate normal vector $\vec x$) would be "very close" to $1$: $$ \Pr_{\vec x \sim \mathcal{N}(\vec 0, \mathbb{I}_d)}\left[ \Big| (\vec a - \vec b) \cdot \vec x \Big| \leq \Big| \vec a \cdot \vec x \Big| \right] $$ i.e. that this probability is $\geq 1-\epsilon$ or something like that.

Do you have any thoughts / intuition on how it can be proven that this probability is "very close" (in $\epsilon$-terms) to $1$?